# How do I check the primeness of ideals of a finitely generated algebra over a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

In other words, how do I check whether the algebraic set given by a set of polynomial equations is irreducible? For example, I encountered the following example when working through Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry:

> Show that $k[x,y,z,w]/(wz-xy,wy-x^2,xz-y^2)$ is an integral surface. (Here $k$ is a field.)

I know that if the ideal is principal, then we only have to check that the generator is prime. However, I don't know of any efficient way to check primeness in general. How does one approach such problems? In particular, how do I show that $(wz-xy,wy-x^2,xz-y^2)$ is a prime ideal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A general criterion is: An ideal is prime iff the corresponding quotient ring is a domain.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60957/how-to-determine-whether-an-ideal-is-prime-or-not-by-an-algorithm

Comment: In this particular case, one can show that this ideal is the kernel of the map
$k(x,y,z,w)\to k(u,v)$ defined by $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto(u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3)$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks! I guess this question is a (cross-site) duplicate then. Should one flag it as duplicate?